# Chrome stops Javascript when console is opened

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, developer-tools

I'm not sure if this is a new update, or a browser setting I changed when I was drunk, but basically when I open the Chrome Developer Console, Javascript becomes blocked on that page (And the Javascript Blocked icon appears in the address bar).

Even after closing the console, Javascript is still disabled, until I refresh the page.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Do you often change browser settings while drunk?

Comment: It's my favorite drunk pastime

Comment: This happened to me too! No idea how it got set (I only use the developer tools sober). Perhaps we should report a bug to Google? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can disable Javascript on pages where the Developer tools panel is open.

To re-enable it go to the *Developer tool* settings and uncheck the *Disable Javascript* option on the *Preferences tab*.

[image]

Comment: Please mark it as an aswer if it solved your problem

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I did try at the time, but there was a time ban on it ...

Comment: There's also a "Restore defaults and reload" button. Looks like that also did the trick and may have solved other problems.

Comment: I can't find it... Mac user

Comment: The settings page of the developer tools has been redesigned, on the preferences tab in the most right column you will find the Disable Javascript option

Comment: I have updated the answer with a picture